# How to mount file inside docker in docker?

Tags: docker

docker container start with

```
- /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

Inside docker container i want to call another docker something like this

```
docker run --rm --net none -v /new/test.py:/new/test.py test-python timeout 5 make --silent -C /new/ test
```

but i get an error

> docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create shim: OCI runtime
> create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process:
> error during container init: error mounting to rootfs  flags: 0x5000:
> not a directory: unknown: Are you trying to mount a directory onto a
> file (or vice-versa)? Check if the specified host path exists and is
> the expected type.

Without the -v parameter, the launch itself is processed

and When I call the same code not from the docker, everything works out

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember, while you may have exposed the docker socket inside your container, *the docker daemon is running on your host*. It's not inside any container. So when you write:

```
... -v /new/test.py:/new/test.py ...
```

Docker is looking for `/new/test.py` relative to the root of your *host* filesystem, not inside the container filesystem.

In general, bind mounts aren't going to work in a useful fashion. Named volumes will work fine, of course.